# entering an entire record in a table automatically updates the respective fields in other table

Tags: mysql

I have got two tables...Table 1 is having 4 columns as : 'p_id' , 'email' , 'password', 'contact_number'.......'p_id' is the PRIMARY KEY of the Table 1.

Table 2 has got 5 columns, they are : 'p_id' , 'password' ,'email' , 'contact_number' , 'cust_id' ...................here 'p_id' is serving as the FOREIGN KEY from Table 1.

Now my question is that if we insert the three fields in Table 1 then is there any way that the "respective" same fields in the Table 2 also gets updated with the same values from Table 1?

I'm new to this forum so apologies if i didn't match the question asking etiquette...:).

Comment: 1. Please don't use password as a primary key. People would be able to bruteforce signups and be able to find passwords that are being used by anyone just if it returned an error due to the fact that the column was not unique. I would just suggest when executing a query to update table 1, update table 2 at the same time.

Comment: OK..thnxx..i'll change that...but any ideas about the main question.?

Comment: Look at triggers. They can be used for that purpose.

Comment: A trigger would do the job, but do you really need two separate tables?

Comment: Actually my intention is to create a user registration panel....the user will enter the respective details and the same details would be inserted in the second table....so the next time user log-in the second table would show up validating the inputs form variables.

Comment: Password? Surely email?!?!

Comment: You've me-designed this completely. Primary key shouldn't be the password; the two tables aren't normalized; there is no apparent need for two tables at all. Rethink.

Comment: I know I did mistake...all I was just looking for the main concept behind the question....well now the question is edited...:)

Comment: Not one mistake. Several mistakes. You're missing the point. The question only *exists* because of the mis-design. Properly normalized data doesn't need a facility like this.

Comment: so what would be the correct one ...i want to create a login/registration panel and present the user database after he/she successfully login the page.

Comment: A single table, as far as I can see. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I avoid triggers because they cause additional maintenance considerations.  http://www.ducea.com/2007/07/25/dumping-mysql-stored-procedures-functions-and-triggers/ for instance.  Of course it can be done.  But I suspect the authors of SQL standards intended foreign keys to be used to solve this problem.

You can add FOREIGN KEY constraints with multiple indexes, so if I'm not mistaken, you can use such syntax so that when the data is changed in the one table, it will also be changed in the other.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]

reference_option:
    RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION
```

That having been said, I do recommend looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form - you don't need or want to store the same information in more than one place.  Instead, as others have suggested, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html - use JOIN to combine the tables when you select from them.

Thank you for providing the clarification about your use case:

> actually the concept is that there would be a registration panel ..the
>   user will enter his data ...these will get stored in the second
>   table....now when he/she login this data will be matched and his/her
>   details from the database will be loaded

from what you describe, you don't seem to need 2 tables at all.  You store their values, they supply them, and you check to see if they match.  Why do you need the other table for that?  Simply execute a WHERE clause to check whether the values they provided exist in the database.  Where does the second table even come in?

I sincerely hope you consider this advice: Authentication is about the worst thing to build yourself, so much more so if you're learning.  You might want to post a question to the appropriate programming community regarding the use of a pre-built auth layer that would meet your needs.  It would probably store the data in a database much like yours, but would include valuable sercurity considerations to protect not just you, but also your users.

For instance, storing a plain text password in the database is a terrible practice.  If your site suffered a data access breach such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection your users' emails *and* passwords would be exposed, and in that case the attacker has a valuable login set that is probably used on some other website ( of course you should never reuse your passwords, but obviously lots of folks do ).  Now you've exposed your users' accounts *all across the internet*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Password_verification explains how usually only a one way hash of the password ( eg sha256 ) is required to authorize the user.  If you want to be really cool, you can even hash before you *send* the data to the server: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76939/why-almost-no-webpages-hash-passwords-in-the-client-before-submitting-and-hashi .  This works because a good hash can't be reversed ( you'd have to brute force, a computationally untenable operation) but always yield the same results with the same input.

If you're getting started programming, why not leave the auth to an open source drop in solution and focus on the guts of your app logic?  It's what the pros do.

Comment: Why do anything? Why not just normalize the database and eliminate the problem?

Comment: It's true @EJP, at so many levels.  I hope I've fleshed out what you're saying here sufficiently in the answer.

Comment: @DanFarrell thnx for the support and your humble advice....I really appreciate that...this is my first ever effort handling the practical implication of a database so such foolish mistakes are inevitable...but the way you answered...i m really happy...you helped me a lot...thanx once again...:)..
And we all knw that knowing the concepts and to apply them practically...ther's a lot a way difference between these both....nd that's what m facing...

Comment: @Blackwood All I can say to that is 'rubbish'. Complete and utter nonsense. The NAA flag is simply not intended for the purpose you are using it for.

Comment: @EJP I agree that the answer in its current form is a good one. When I flagged it, it consisted of a single line that did not, in my mind, answer the question. It has since been replaced with essentially a different (and much better) answer.

Comment: Yeah, this answer was terrible and has since been corrected, hence the confusion.

Comment: @Blackwood If this is now an answer you should therefore remove your comment that says it isn't.

Comment: @EJP You are right, and I should have removed my comment earlier (but I have done so now). Unfortunately, the comment was just a byproduct of me flagging the post as "Not an Answer", and there isn't any way for me to withdraw the flag. However, as the answer is now improved, I don't think it is in danger of being closed. Perhaps we should both remove our comments to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Use an AFTER INSERT trigger:

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER Table1_AI
  AFTER INSERT ON Table1
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE Table2 t2
    SET t2.password = NEW.password,
        t2.email = NEW.email,
        t2.contact_number = NEW.contact_number
    WHERE t2.p_id  = NEW.p_id;
END;//

delimiter ;
```

This presumes that the row to be modified already exists in Table2. If it might not you might want to use an `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` statement in the body of the trigger.

Best of luck.

Comment: @DanFarrell Far inferior to what exactly? And what does 'spirit this directly' mean?

Comment: @DanFarrell - the [ON UPDATE clause of a FOREIGN KEY constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) could be used to update the foreign key value (`p_id` in this case) but would do nothing for the other columns.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your link affirms that the foreign key could include multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

Classic denormalization problem. The correct solution is to redesign your data. The real problem here is that the two tables aren't normalized, so you have repeated data. This is a violation of 3NF, and it is the only reason your question even exists. Even if you solve this part of it with some dreadful hack, you will then have the further problem of having to update both tables at the same time, and what to do (which is right?) if they ever get out of sync.

I can't see a single reason why you even need two tables, but if you do the second one should consist only of a foreign key into the first one, and then columns for all the data that *isn't in* the first one. In this case, everything starting from `cust_id, ...`

Comment: Hmmm...i got it...u are sayin' this because the attributes are of same name in the two tables....I guessed it won't affect because the queries go all well and it didn't show any errors....

Comment: I am saying you are violating third normal form, both with your design and your question. If you don't know what that is, you should look it up, and you certainly shouldn't be designing relational databases until you do know. No repeated data.

Comment: Well thanx...i take your comment as a positive advice....i knw the concepts...just i dnt hv enough skills to apply them....
ok so if i redesign it in a gud way would that suffice my conditions or i can do evrything from a single table only?

Comment: Either. I would use a single table. You still haven't told us why you think you need two, and waffling about a user registration panel doesn't constitute an answer to that.

Comment: sorry....i think i'm being stupid....actually the concept is that there would be a registration panel ..the user will enter his data ...these will get stored in the second table....now when he/she login this data will be matched and his/her details from the database will be loaded....plzz don't demoralize me...first tym i'm being pragmatic but i knw it's goin too wrong...:(

Comment: Nobody is trying to demoralize you, and comments like that are out of place. I can only repeat, you've got this wrong. Repeated data in any database is a sure sign of mis-design. What you need is a table of users, containing nothing more than a username and password (hashed) and anything else like an email that goes directly with the user, and a system-generated user ID, which is used as a foreign key in any other table that needs it. You do not need to repeat the user data anywhere. You use JOIN.